# Download pdf file to blob storage in data factory

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

How can I in a datafactory pipeline download a pdf file(or any type of file)? to a blob storage , this file are searching throutgh an api but they are in base 64

[image]

Comment: Assuming you are using C#, there's a code example here: https://azurelessons.com/upload-and-download-file-in-azure-blob-storage/#How_to_download_a_file_from_the_Azure_blob_storage_using_C

Comment: which API you use to download the file?

Comment: Hi @willy sepulveda, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hello Leon Yue, it is a rest api that returns a json structure and within this structure is a field with the content of the base 64 file which must be passed through the copy data activity from azura data factory to a storage blob

Comment: @willysepulveda did you try the REST connector?  Create the REST as Source in copy active and Sink is Blob Storage.

Comment: Hi @LeonYue, I have already created the linked service and the data set to extract the information, however the api returns a json structure and I only need to save the blob a field of that structure, in the image is the field that should be stored, but the api returns all that json structure

Comment: @willysepulveda you only want to store the key of file content?

Comment: Hi @LeonYue, I need to store the value of the Key that is in base 64, in datafactory through the delimitedtex dataset I can store txt files, but how can I save PDF and Word files that are in base 64? as well as it is in the image where that file is extension docx

Comment: @willysepulveda please try the binary fromat.

Comment: Hi @LeonYue, I have tried, but the api will return a set of keys but I only need the value of the key from the content file, the api does not allow filtering that key, any idea how I can filter it on the source side in the copy data??

Comment: @willysepulveda there is another idea you can try , Data Flow:  REST as source + derived column(filter the column/key) + sink.  If all of these can't work, I afraid to say data factory can't achievet.

Comment: @LeonYue, during the weekend I was trying to do this by DataFlow, but unfortunately it is not possible to do this type of integration by Data Factory, for this reason I will have to make a small logic app that allows me to do it, I do it by logic app because it is what represents the lowest cost to me

Comment: @willysepulveda all right, hope you will doing well!  May I add these to my answer?

Comment: hello @LeonYue, of course, and thank you very much for your valuable help

Comment: @willysepulveda you're welcome. If the answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very sure which API you download the pdf file from, you could think about these connectors in Data Factory:

- **[REST connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest)** specifically support copying data from RESTful APIs;
- **[HTTP connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http)** is generic to retrieve data from any HTTP endpoint,
  e.g. to download file. Before REST connector becomes available, you
  may happen to use the HTTP connector to copy data from RESTful API,
  which is supported but less functional comparing to REST connector.
- **[Web table connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-web-table)** extracts table content from an HTML webpage.

These may achieve your request.

Update：

At last now, you decided to choose Logic app to do it for cost concerns:

- "During the weekend I was trying to do this by DataFlow, but
  unfortunately it is not possible to do this type of integration by
  Data Factory, for this reason I will have to make a small logic app
  that allows me to do it, I do it by logic app because it is what
  represents the lowest cost to me."